# Prevent javascript from running when using Internet Explorer programmatically through VBA

Tags: javascript, vba, excel

I am trying to access the innerHTML property of a webpage by using `ie.Navigate` in VBA and then pulling the `.Document.Body.innerHTML` into a string. However, the source code of this page has the following Javascript, which constantly redirects the page if window.opener is not = true:

```
if(!window.opener)
{
    window.location='index.php';
}
```

This redirect happens before I can even get access to the page's HTML, and as a result I pull in index.php instead of the webpage I'm working on. Is there any workaround for this, other than disabling javascript completely in IE?

Comment: Use a proxy that strips that statement

Comment: How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You need a server where you can grab the page using curl or other http access. Then you can pull whatever from the page or strip the code before  sending it to the VBA

Comment: Is there an easier way, as I don't think I'll be able to do this?

Comment: No. If there is script to navigate away from the page, then you need to remove that script somehow.

Comment: Is there no way to set window.opener = true, and go from there?

Comment: Only by opening in a new window

Comment: How would I do this (open a new window) this using VBA?

Comment: I have no idea. Never used VBA - but if you can inject script you could try setting the window.opener